# Reading commands from another file in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

see i want to use `source` command in my shell script. Now when i type source on terminal it shows like

```
-bash: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
```

now when i use this in my shell script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
source
```

and save as test.sh

and  run then get like this

```
./test.sh: 2: source: not found
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Source requires an argument. What do you expect it to do without one?

Comment: i know it but here problem is source command is not finding...if i give argument still it will not work..

Comment: `source file` in bash or csh is a command that reads commands from `file` into the current shell (either script or interactive session).  The more portable version of this is the *dot* command `. file`. This is supported on all common unix shells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You run your script with `sh`, not with `bash`. `source` does not exist in plain `sh`, but you can use `.` instead, it means the same thing.

```
#!/bin/sh
. /path/to/other/script
function_defined_in_other_script
```

Comment: Indeed, use `. file` to make it work across different shells.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld: `.` does not work in `dash` (the default `sh` on Ubuntu). Neither is it documented in its manpage.

Comment: `$ . ./test_dot.sh `  Results in `This is test_dot.sh, called from dash` on my vagrant linux box.   (file contains `echo This is test_dot.sh, called from $0
`)

Comment: @HenkLangeveld: my mistake. Tried with a file which did exist system wide as well … – still, I cannot find it in the manpage.

Comment: It's in man dash, three paragraphs down in the `Builtins` section

Comment: True. Seems like I cannot search for a full stop with word boundaries (`\<\.\>`) in `less`. Thanks!